# error: package net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder does not exist

Tags: java

I want to ask something regarding this error. I am using dynamicreports to generate report and after i compiled and run the program this error occured.

```
  error: package net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder does not exist
  error: package net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder does not exist 
  error: package net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.column does not exist
  error: package net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.component does not exist
  error: package net.sf.dynamicreports.report.builder.datatype does not exist
  error: package net.sf.dynamicreports.report.constant does not exist
  error: package net.sf.dynamicreports.report.exception does not exist
```

what is lacking in my code in order this package to be recognized by the JVM during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that dynamicreports  is not present in the code Run path..can you please specify how you are running your code.

You can use the following command :

```
java -classpath <path of dynamicreports jar>;your_jar MainClass
```

Comment: maybe that's what I am lacking the "path of dynamicreports jar" which is not present in the code Run path.

Comment: can you tell me if how to add the dynamicreports in order to be present in runt path?

Comment: do you have a Jar for dynamicreports..and what is the location of the file

Comment: no I dont have one. But I'm using Maven in order to create a project, but unfortunately I'm having hard time figuring out if how to create a jar for dynamic reports.

Comment: You can search online for dynamicreports jar. Moreover Maven might have ways to automatically take care of path dpeendencies. Unfortunately I am not a maven expert...sorry !!

Comment: I have already created a jar for dynamicreport using maven and it is located inside subdirectory named "target" unfortunately i dont know how to use this dynamicreport jar file so that the packages mention aboved will be recognized by the JVM during runtime. Can you give me an idea if how to do it, regardless if your using maven or not? thanks in advance